# Page request manager parser error exception

Tags: asp.net

I have created one form. In that form, after clicking on button shows data in grid.This is working properly, no problem. When I am writing Response.Write(), inside the function to find out the sql query, getting this error. I used update panel, inside that put button and gridview.

Answer (score 2):

Response.write can't be use in updatepanel .

use label or span to show data

Refer : http://www.jnouel.net/post/2009/07/06/ResponseWrite-and-UpdatePanel.aspx

http://www.dotnetpete.com/post/2008/09/18/ResponseWrite-within-an-update-panel.aspx